# Looking up multiple items in a table

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write an Excel formula to return a value from the table below:

```
Q   Y   Mean        1      2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9 
1   4   1301    <1183   1183    1233    1283    1333    1383    1433    1483    1533
2   4   1306    <1189   1189    1239    1289    1339    1389    1439    1489    1539
3   4   1317    <1200   1200    1250    1300    1350    1400    1450    1500    1550
4   4   1333    <1214   1214    1264    1314    1364    1414    1464    1514    1564
1   5   1346    <1225   1225    1275    1325    1375    1425    1475    1525    1575
2   5   1360    <1235   1235    1285    1335    1385    1435    1485    1535    1585
3   5   1372    <1245   1245    1295    1345    1395    1445    1495    1545    1595
4   5   1390    <1255   1255    1305    1355    1405    1455    1505    1555    1605
1   6   1403    <1266   1266    1316    1366    1416    1466    1516    1566    1616
2   6   1416    <1276   1276    1326    1376    1426    1476    1526    1576    1626
3   6   1425    <1285   1285    1335    1385    1435    1485    1535    1585    1635
4   6   1426    <1291   1291    1341    1391    1441    1491    1541    1591    1641
```

I want to be able to identify a year, then a quarter, and then according to a pupil's score, return the corresponding standard nine figure in the top line.

What's the best way to do this? I've tried INDEX and MATCH functions without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy for a multiple lookup like this is to concatenate the indices together to form a unique index.  This unique index will let you get the correct row combining the year/quarter.

The second piece of this is using INDEX to return an entire row from your table of scores which can then be used to find the score in the table with MATCH.

Once you have the score column, you can return the nine from there. Using INDEX again.

The end result is an INDEX-MATCH-INDEX-MATCH.  It made more sense to me by splitting the formulas into different cells, but I combined them together below.

Here is what I started with.  I added the ID column that combines the year/quarter.

[image: image of workup]

Formula in D3 = `=B3&"-"&C3`, copied down to the end.

Cells C17 and C18 are inputs.

Cell C19 = `=C17&"-"&C18`

Cell C20 (Score) is an input.

Cell C21 is the messy one which combines the logic described above: `=INDEX(F2:N2,MATCH(C20,INDEX(F3:N14,MATCH(C19,D3:D14,0),),1))`

Here is that formula expanded with color so you can see somewhat is going on:

[image: showing formula with colors]

Comment: Thanks, so much! I'd been struggling with getting the Index-Match function to work this way. Great that the function can be performed in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have:

[image]

We place the desired quarter in **A1** and the desired year in **B1**, and in **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(C1:C14,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$3:$A$14=$A$1)*($B$3:$B$14=$B$1)*(ROW(3:14))))
```

and copy across. This gives us:

[image]